Passing blob URLs from main to renderer in Electron
I want to load images from paths given by the user (possibly modify them) and to display them using electron.
I used to use Electron many years ago and then it was quite easy since access to 'fs' node module was still unrestricted. Now, if I want to use 'fs' in the renderer I get error messages like this one:

Uncaught Error: Module "fs" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "fs.existsSync" in client code.

So my solution was to load the file in the main process to a blob, create an URL for the blob and pass it to the renderer using IPC. This is a minimal example:
main.ts
export async function loadWebpFromFile(path: string) {
    const fileContents = await fs.promises.readFile(path, null);
    const webpImage = new Blob([fileContents], {
      type: 'image/webp',
    });

    return URL.createObjectURL(webpImage);
}

ipcMain.handle(
  'getWebpUrl',
  (event: any, path: string) => loadWebpFromFile(path),
);

preload.ts
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('fromMain', {
  getWebpUrl: async (path: string) => {
    return ipcRenderer.invoke('getWebpUrl', path);
  },
});

App.ts
const App = () => {
  const [webpUrl, setWebpUrl] = useState<string>("");
  
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const webpUrl = await (window as any).fromMain.getWebpUrl ("C:\\images\\a.webp");
      setWebpUrl(webpUrl);
    })();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>ElectroVite</h1>
      <img src={webpUrl} />
    </div>
  );
};

But I get the following error in the console:

Not allowed to load local resource: blob:nodedata:985f076a-f83d-4fb8-82e3-5826401afed1  localhost/:1

So how can I exactly access this URL. Why is it even blocked? Or perhaps should I use a completely different approach?
The example is based on the following Typescript-React-Vite boilerplaite:
https://github.com/guasam/electrovite-react
